# Plist rewriting over old data each time I save a new data

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have a simple objective c program in which I save user entered data in a plist. But when I try to save multiple data in my plist it rewrites over the old data and I can just get only one data in my plist, i.e. the last data that the user has entered. Here is my code below to save the data -

```
- (IBAction)savedata:(id)sender
{

    NSError *error;
    NSString *arr= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

   arr=[arr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datalist.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray *valuearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:_nametextfield.text forKey:@"NAME"];
    [valuearray addObject:dict];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:arr])
    {
        NSLog(@"FILE EXIST");
        self.bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"datalist" ofType:@"plist" ];//NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”data” ofType:@”plist”];
        NSLog(@"%@",_bundle);

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:_bundle toPath: arr error:&error];

        [valuearray writeToFile:arr atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@",arr);

        //6
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"FILE DOESN'T EXIST");
        [valuearray writeToFile:arr atomically:YES];
    }


}
```

And here is my fetch data -

```
- (IBAction)fetchdata:(id)sender
{
    NSString *arr= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    arr=[arr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datalist.plist"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:arr])
    {
        NSArray *dict=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arr];
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);

    }

}
```

Now I can only retrieve the last entered data and I don't know why is it causing so much problem. Please somebody help me on this. I have also attached a screenshot of my main bundle.[image]

Comment: The call to `NSArray writeToFile:atomically:` replaces the file. You need to write all of the data you want in the file every time you write to the file.

Comment: @rmaddy So how to do that ?

Comment: The array you write needs to have all data, not just new data.

Comment: @rmaddy So how to do that any idea or tips or code to add to my existing code?

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks I have did it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the save part with this -

```
- (IBAction)savedata:(id)sender
{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *arr= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    arr=[arr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datalist.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray *valuearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:_titletextfield.text forKey:@"NAME"];
    [valuearray addObject:dict];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:arr])
    {
        NSLog(@"FILE EXIST");
        //self.bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"datalist" ofType:@"plist" ];//NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”data” ofType:@”plist”];
        // NSLog(@"%@",_bundle);

        //[fileManager copyItemAtPath:_bundle toPath: arr error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *valuearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:arr];
        if (dict.count)
        {
            [valuearray addObject:dict];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"data not retrieved");
        }

        [valuearray writeToFile:arr atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@",arr);

        //6
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"FILE DOESN'T EXIST");
        [valuearray writeToFile:arr atomically:YES];
    }

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"sucess" message:@"successfully saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thanks to @rmaddy.